# Add class "copyMe" and enable button, apply the same behavior for checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a code where I add a class `copyMe` and also toggle button enabled if at least one of the checkboxes is changed (checked/unchecked), this is the code behind that behavior:

```
// Enable button #btnAplicarNorma and add copyMe class when any of the checkbox changes 
$('#resultadoNormaBody').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function () {
    var $my_checkbox = $(this);
    var $my_tr = $my_checkbox.closest('tr');

    if ($my_checkbox.prop('checked')) {
        $my_tr.addClass('copyMe');
    }

    var $all_checkboxes = $my_checkbox.closest('tbody').find('input[type=checkbox]');
    $all_checkboxes.each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('#btnAplicarNorma').prop('disabled', false);
            return false;
        }
        $('#btnAplicarNorma').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

Now I'm trying to apply the same behavior but this time for a checkbox that toggle all checkboxes and I'm doing something wrong since I don't get any set of matches elements on `$all_checkboxes` var. This is the code I'm trying for this one:

```
// Enable button #btnAplicarNorma and add copyMe class when #toggleCheckboxNorma changes
$('#resultadoNorma').on('change', '#toggleCheckboxNorma', function () {
    var $my_checkbox = $(this);
    var $all_checkboxes = $my_checkbox.closest('tbody').find('input[type=checkbox]');

    console.log($my_checkbox);
    console.log($all_checkboxes);

    $all_checkboxes.each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass('copyMe');
            $('#btnAplicarNorma').prop('disabled', false);
            return false;
        }

        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('copyMe');
        $('#btnAplicarNorma').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

I tried also changing this line:

```
var $all_checkboxes = $my_checkbox.closest('tbody').find('input[type=checkbox]');
```

to this:

```
var $all_checkboxes = $('#resultadoNorma').closest('tbody').find('input[type=checkbox]');
```

But I got the same, so the idea is when I change `#toggleCheckboxNorma` all the `tr` should get the class `copyMe` and also `#btnAplicarNorma` should be enable if it's the contrary I should go back and remove the class and also disabled back the button. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ot96p9mL/4/) with code example. Take care, in the fiddle all the content is loaded by default but in my code TR are generated dynamically by a Ajax call, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is your function `marcarTodosCheck()` is interrupting. Add `.trigger("change")` after altering the property, as below. Is this your desired result? See example: http://jsfiddle.net/ot96p9mL/5/

```
function marcarTodosCheck(selChk, tableBody) {
    $(selChk).on('click', function () {
        var $toggle = $(this).is(':checked');
        $(tableBody).find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", $toggle).trigger("change");
    });

    $(tableBody).find("input:checkbox").on('click', function () {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(selChk).prop("checked", false).trigger("change");
        } else if ($(tableBody).find("input:checkbox").length == $(tableBody).find("input:checkbox:checked").length) {
            $(selChk).prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Also: In your current code, when unchecked, copyme class is not removed. Here's an updated, working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ot96p9mL/13/